# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments, how do i overcome this error?

Tags: c++, c

i am receiving this error for this section of my code:

```
int R[] = {3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 5};
int L= dist (R(0),R(1)) + (R(1),R(2)) + (R(2),R(3)) + (R(3),R(4)) + (R(4),R(5));
```

im not sure how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

You should access array items using `[]` and not `()`.

Also, you should apply the function `dist` to each pair of items separately:

```
int L= dist(R[0],R[1]) + dist(R[1],R[2]) + dist(R[2],R[3]) + dist(R[3],R[4]) + dist(R[4],R[5]);
```

You can write this in a loop too:

```
int L = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    L += dist(R[i], R[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To access individual array elements, use `[` and `]` (not `(` and `)`)

```
int L = dist (R[0], R[1]) ...
```

You probably also want to call the `dist()` function for the other pairs

```
dist(R[0], R[1]) + dist(R[1], R[2]) + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious error - accessing array elements with `()` instead of `[]`, there are some other logical issues with your code. The expression

```
dist (R[0],R[1]) + (R[1],R[2])
```

will not do what you think. It will evaluate `dist (R(0),R(1))` and add that to `R(2)`. The term `R(1)` has no effect on the computation. That is how the comma operator `,` works.

You probably want

```
int L= dist(R[0],R[1]) + dist(R[1],R[2]) + dist(R[2],R[3]) + dist(R[3],R[4]) + dist(R[4],R[5]);
```

instead of

```
int L= dist(R[0],R[1]) + (R[1],R[2]) + (R[2],R[3]) + (R[3],R[4]) + (R[4],R[5]);
```

You'd probably have returned in 5 minutes asking why your output was different than what you expected.